# Where can I most easily farm for resplendent chests in Act 2?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm finding that with my current gear, taking down packs of elites in Inferno Act 2 is a slow, tricky, and painful process. Rather than slog through elite packs, I'd like to toss on some Magic Find gear and try to quickly hunt down some resplendent chests. I find that it's fairly easy to kite all the dangerous mobs to a far-off corner of the dungeon, die, and then make a bee-line for the chests.

The only problem right now is that I don't know where the best place to look for these are. The only one I know to look for is the Treasure Vault of Khan Dakab in the Oasis.

- Which other dungeons in Act 2 can contain resplendent chests?
- Are there any that are guaranteed to always appear?
- Are there any that are easy to check for because they're always close to a waypoint when they do appear?

Comment: There used to be one that had a 100% spawn chance then they patched it to 50%; still decent odds unless the dungeon it's in was random too.

Comment: Your best bet would be to farm the Warden/Butcher. Using equipment or selling extras should net you a fair amount of gear quickly

Comment: @Domocus I've done that. My gear has gotten as good as it's likely to from there, and it's not dropping the tier of items that I'm after.

Comment: @NickT They patched it to not only be 50% instead of 100%, but also to be Normal instead of Resplendent.

Comment: @Sterno - didn't know the Normal change, just visited the dungeon yest. (on Normal difficulty) to see what it was and disappointed at not getting a golden chest, oh well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty large number of resplendent chests while farming for liquid rainbow; the Mysterious Cave Level 2 always had one for me on Normal.  I would say I found the Cave every 5 minutes on average.

I got my average time to check for the Cave down to 28 seconds when farming for the rainbow.

Start on quest "Betrayer of the Horadrim" and run through the sewers until you first exit into the Oasis.  This will trigger a checkpoint, and your game will begin here every time.  Run down the corridor and stick to the southern wall, taking the first branch.  This will be a short branch, with water under foot, leading to two huts.  If the Alchemist is here, kill the ghosts and go into the Mysterious cave.  If not, loot the bones/chest/iron wolf in the corner, hit your town portal, and exit game.

From now on, every game you create will start you a very, very short run away from this location.  It will always be in the same place, so checking is very quick, and you will occasionally see a cellar, or a champion pack for slightly more loot options.

Bonus points if the Treasure Vault always spawns near the Oasis entrance, but I don't know where you've been checking for it.

Answer (score 0):

magic find DOES NOT apply to chests.  read:
http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/equipment#magic-find

Comment: The question was asked prior to 1.0.3 which removed MF on chests